# What type should I use instead of any?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

### Code

Slider.tsx

```
import { useSelector, connect } from "react-redux";
import { ProductType, ProductItem, StateType } from "types";
const Slider = ({ products, number }: any) => {    ------------------> what type?
//  const number = useSelector((state: StateType) => state.number);
  return (
    <S.Slider>
         <S.SliderWrapper widthSize={number}>
           {products}
             ...
         <S.SliderWrapper>
    </S.Slider>
  );
};

export default connect((state: StateType, { products }: ProductType) => {
  return { number: state.number, products };
}, null)(Slider);
```

types.ts

```
export interface ProductItem {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  price: number;
  bgcolor: string;
  colors: { code: string; img: any }[];
}
export interface ProductType {
  products: ProductItem[];
}

export interface StateType {
  number: number;
}
```

I set the type on connect now, and I don't know the type of prop of Slider Component, so I set it to 'any' and it works well.

How can I change it to put in the type instead of "any"?

Comment: if you know products, and number, you can create an object with those types in it and use that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an interface describing the type of `products`. I assume that number is type of `number` and create a product since I don't know the shape of your object, adapt it to your needs. So you will have something like that :

```js
export interface IProduct{
  id: number,
  name: string,
}
```

And, either create an interface for the props of your slider, as follow :

```js
interface ISliderProps {
  products: Array<Product>,
  number: number
}

export const Slider = ({products, number}: ISliderProps) => {
  // ...
}
```

or define it directly next to your props :

```js
export const Slider = ({products, number}: {products: Array<Product>, number: number}) => {
  // ...
}
```

You can also use the `React.FC<>` interface that allow you to type your props this way :

```js
export const Slider: React.FC<ISliderProps> = ({product, number}) {
  // ...
}
```

But note that this last solution expose your component to `children` by default, which is not what you always want.

Comment: I import the type from types.ts.

Comment: @holim That doesn't change my answer, you can use them. You don't seem to have a `Products` type so create one and use it as per my recommandation. We don't know the shape of your products props so we can't help you more.

Comment: In 'type.ts', the interface ProductType declared products as type.

Comment: Yes I didn't see it sorry. Still, there is no problem... just use it : `const Slider = ({ products, number }: { products: ProductType, number: number }) => {...}`